# Switch between JPA and MongoDB with only configuration changes

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot

How to build a `Spring Boot application` which can switch between `JPA` and `MongoDB` with only **configuration** changes?

Answer (score 1):

Well both JPA and MongoDB config are basically beans, in case of JPA it's some kind of [DataSource()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/package-summary.html) bean and incase of MongoDB, it's the  [MongoTemplate()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) bean. But, if you are configuring the beans using `application.yaml` with built in properties like spring.data `spring.data.xxx` or `spring.mongo.xxx`
If I understood correctly what you meant by

> configuration changes

then you are meaning feature toogle. In that case there are a number of ways to achieve that in Spring. [@ConditionalOnPropety](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html), [@ConditionaOnMissingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html), Spring profiling - [@ActiveProfile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) etc.

It basically depends on your particulary use case. Aditionally you can make disable any bean injection like as follows:

> (@Autowired(required=false))

That way, any bean injection can be avoided.

Comment: thanks for your repense  but to understand what i mean could u please see this publication:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727922/switch-between-jpa-and-mongodb-with-only-configuration-changes-with-spring-boot